# Use tkinter OptionMenu variable in SQL query (sqlite3) ? Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, tkinter

I am trying to make it so the data in a row of my database is summed and then outputted to the user. This row can be chosen by the user depending on which option is selected from the OptionMenu widget in tkinter.

When testing for 'Wires', the output of this is '0.0', but it should be 4 as I have a 3, 1 & and 0 in my database.

Please ignore my illogical flow of code. This is just a section from my larger project.

Thanks a lot.

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3

root = Tk()

def Database():
    module_label = Label(root, text="Enter a module to review:")
    module_label.grid(column=1, row=9, pady=25, padx=200)
    global module
    module = StringVar()
    module.set("Wires")
    module_select = OptionMenu(root, module, "Wires", "The_Button", "Passwords")
    module_select.grid(column=1, row=10, pady=15)
    module_done_button = Button(root, text="Submit", command=ModuleData)
    module_done_button.grid(column=1, row=10, sticky=E, padx=100)

    global database_text
    database_text = [module_label, module_select, module_done_button]

def ModuleData():
    for x in database_text:
        x.grid_forget()
    conn = sqlite3.connect ('KTANE_test.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    result = c.execute ("SELECT SUM(?) FROM test", (module.get(), )).fetchone()[0]
    print (result)
    

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


conn = sqlite3.connect ('KTANE_test.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(
            serial_number text,
            Wires integer DEFAULT 0,
            The_Button integer DEFAULT 0,
            Passwords integer DEFAULT 0)""")
                    
conn.commit()
conn.close()

Database()
```

Comment: Can you really use placeholders for column names?

Comment: @TheLizzard I don't think that would matter as new connection is opened again.

Comment: @CoolCloud My bad. Didn't see that OP opened another connection

Comment: @CoolCloud How do you mean? I'd like the result of the OptionMenu widget to determine the row that has the data summed if that makes sense :3

Comment: Use `print()` and enusure the values are what you expect.

Comment: @CoolCloud Replacing the statement with SUM(Wires) works and prints the data successfully, and doing print(module.get()) also prints Wires when selected. Not sure what's going on :/...

Comment: Try: `c.execute(f"SELECT SUM({module.get()}) FROM test").fetchone()[0]`.

Comment: @CoolCloud Yes! Thank you so much! Could you explain why this works / what this is?

Comment: This is because `Sum()` takes a column name. Column names cannot be substituted using placeholder(`?`). Placeholders are used for field values. For columns you have to use whitelisting or something to make sure the column names is always valid.